# How to update nested Apollo Cache 3+ levels deep?

Tags: nuxt.js, apollo, vue-apollo

I have a NuxtJS app with deeply nested data in my Apollo Cache. As an example, my cache could look something like this, where Trips have many Categories which have many Items.

```graphql
ROOT_QUERY
  trips: [Trip]
    0: Trip:1
      categories: [Category]
        0: Category:1
          items: [Item]
            0: Item:1
            1: Item:2
            2: Item:3  
    1: Trip:2
```

I am trying to update the cache after either removing or adding an item to the array of Items located in `trips[0].categories[0]`. What I have works, but only after what seems like 1-2 seconds of delay while it talks to my server and returns a response. It seems to me like `optimisticResponse` is either not working correctly, or the data is too deeply nested to update the UI quick enough.

Here is what my `removeItem` function looks like:

```js
import { remove } from 'lodash';

async function removeItem ({ fields, trip_id, apollo }) {
  return await apollo.mutate({
    mutation: removeItemMutation,
    variables: fields,
    optimisticResponse: {
      __typename: 'Mutation',
      removeItem: {
        __typename: 'item',
        id: fields.item_id,
        name: '',
        weight: 0,
        unit: '',
        price: 0,
        category_id: fields.category_id,
        quantity: 0,
        position: 0,
        created_at: Date.now(),
        updated_at: Date.now()
      }
    },
    update: (cache, { data: { removeItem } }) => {
      console.log({ removeItem });

      // read
      const data = cache.readQuery({ query: tripsQuery });

      // mutate
      const trip = data.trips.find(trip => trip.id === trip_id);
      const category = trip.categories.find(category => category.id === removeItem.category_id);
      remove(category.items, item => item.id === removeItem.id);
      const otherTrips = data.trips.filter(t => t.id !== trip_id);

      // write
      cache.writeQuery({
        query: tripsQuery,
        data: {
          trips: [trip, ...otherTrips]
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

I can see the `console.log` in the update function log twice, so I know that `optimisticResponse` is triggering it at least, I'm just not sure why it appears to be so slow to update the UI? Is there a better way to handle this?

**Update:**

I think I've narrowed it down to the `store.writeQuery()` function. I set my Network speed to "Slow 3G", added a bunch of console logs throughout the update function, and they all were almost instantaneous, which leaves the `writeQuery` function as the culprit. At this point, I'm just honestly not sure what the most effective method is for mutating nested data in the Apollo Cache, and I've been poring over documentation for days now.

**Update 2:**

I ran an interesting experiment where I run a Categories query after my initial large Trips query. From what I understand, it will avoid making a second request because that data already exists in the Cache, and what this also effective does is change my Cache to look something like this:

```graphql
ROOT_QUERY
  trips: [Trip]
    0: Trip:1
      categories: [Category]
        0: Category:1
          items: [Item]
            0: Item:1
            1: Item:2
            2: Item:3  
    1: Trip:2
  categories: [Category]
    0: Category:1
      items: [Item]
        0: Item:1
        1: Item:2
        2: Item:3  
    1: Category:2
    2: Category:3
    3: Category:4
    ...
```

This effectively puts both Categories and Trips at the top level of the ROOT_QUERY, and when I modified the service function to write to  Categories instead, it reduced the time from ~2.5s to ~350ms.

I think this pretty clearly shows that data nested even 3 levels deep like Items originally was what was causing the issues. My only question now is, what's the point of using GraphQL/Apollo if not to return the data exactly as needed the first time around? Why should I have to run multiple queries to pseudo-flatten the Cache?

Comment: Very Good Question

Comment: Thanks, I guess?

Comment: still bad update methods ... mutation of existing objects ... https://ednsquare.com/story/immutable-update-patters-in-javascript-update-objects-and-arrays-------C2NqWN

Comment: Agreed, i actually started implementing immer to avoid mutating them directly

Comment: In react it can be a `<Category/>` component with rendered with/passed `id`, `useQuery` inside to read data directly from cache ('cache-only', no network request), `useMutation` to update `items` array (called from any of rendered `<Item/>`), update cache updating only this category nested objects (doesn't matter `writeQuery` or `writeFragment`) ... should [optimistically] update view immediately ... subcomponents are a cheap and easy abstract in react :D  why to render all from one template? no real/good componentizing in vue?

Answer (score 5):

try `cache.modify()` ([link to api](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#using-cachemodify)) available from `@apollo/client` > v3.
Easy process:

1. identify object to modify
2. specify fields to modify(incl nested)

```js
    client.cache.modify({
      id: client.cache.identify({ __typename: 'OBJ_TYPE_NAME', id: <OBJ_IDENTIFIER> }),
      fields: {
        myField(currentValueOFMyField) {
          return { ...currentValueOFMyField, myNestedField: 'new val' };
        },
      },
    });
```

Hope this'll help someone.